# Using static cells and dynamic prototypes in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I made the tableview a static cell. Since then, I've divided the sections into two sections, section 1 for static cells, section 2 for dynamic prototypes. However, I want to show the dynamic prototype cell in the table view so that section 1 is not visible.

Section 1 (static cell) is good. Note that this app displays movie information using movie api. Section 1 uses static cells to represent movie details, and Section 2 uses dynamic prototype cells to put users' ratings. The details of the movie come out well, but the addition of the dynamic prototype failed.

```
import UIKit

class MovieDetailViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var gradeImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var genreLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var durationLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var reservationRateLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var userRatingLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var audienceLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var sysnopsisTextView: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var directorLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var actorLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var commentTableView: UITableView!

    var movieId: String?
    var movieDetail: MovieDetail?
    var movieCommentList: CommentList?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "CommentsCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "CommentsCell")

        MovieAPI.requestId(id: movieId ?? "") { (movieDetail, error) in

            self.movieDetail = movieDetail

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "\(movieDetail?.title ?? "")"
                self.titleLabel.text = movieDetail?.title
                self.genreLabel.text = movieDetail?.genre
                self.dateLabel.text = movieDetail?.date
                self.durationLabel.text = ",\(movieDetail?.duration ?? 0)분"
                self.reservationRateLabel.text = "\(movieDetail?.reservationRate ?? 0)"
                self.userRatingLabel.text = "\(movieDetail?.userRating ?? 0)"
                self.audienceLabel.text = "\(movieDetail?.audience ?? 0)"
                self.sysnopsisTextView.text = movieDetail?.synopsis
                self.directorLabel.text = movieDetail?.director
                self.actorLabel.text = movieDetail?.actor
                self.gradeImage.image = UIImage(named: "\(movieDetail?.grade ?? 0)")
                self.handleImageResponse()
            }
        }

        MovieAPI.requestComments(id: movieId ?? "") { (movieComments, error) in


        }
    }

    func handleImageResponse() {
        guard let imageURL = URL(string: movieDetail?.image ?? "") else {
            return
        }

        MovieAPI.requestImageFile(url: imageURL, completionHandler: handleImageFileResponse(image:error:))
    }

    func handleImageFileResponse(image: UIImage?, error: Error?) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            self.titleImage.image = image
        }
    }
}

//Dynamic prototype try!! -> failed
extension MovieDetailViewController {

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if section == 1 {
            return movieCommentList?.comments.count ?? 0
        }
        return super.tableView(tableView, numberOfRowsInSection: section)
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellId = "CommentsCell"
        let cell = self.commentTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! CommentsCell

        cell.commentsView.text = movieCommentList?.comments[indexPath.row].contents

        return cell
    }
}
```

The direction I want is to have section 1 (static cell) and section 2 (dynamic prototypes) in order.

Comment: Please explain hows your cells looked like and whats there order are?

Answer (score 0):

To my perspective the default implementation of numberOfRowsInSection() would return 0 rows. You have to specify number of rows for section 2 also.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 1 {
        return movieCommentList?.comments.count ?? 0
    } 
    //Return number as per your requirement for section 2 
    return 2
}
```